# How can I develop a python script to run a written command from a .txt file?

Tags: python

I have a bunch of previous commands written on a .txt file and I want to be able to have a way to write a script that can execute these commands straight up from python rather having to keep typing these commands over and over again .

So , I was wondering if that's possible to just have a python script that can pull a bunch of previous command written on a .txt file and execute it.

Thanks

The commands in the .txt file are SSH commands

Comment: Are they python statements or shell commands?

Comment: You can replace the extension `.txt` to `.py` and then you can simply run it through your IDE.

Comment: well if you have python commands inside the text file you can type something like `python commands.txt` and if you have shell commands you run `bash commands.txt`although changing the file extension to `.py` is for knowing that there is python code written there

Comment: you could also read in your text file and use the `eval()`-function on the "text" you retrieve from the text file - if it is executable code, it will be by the `eval()`-function.

Comment: They are shell commands that I want to execute.

Comment: @ABhelp have you tried my solution bellow? Let me know if it works for your case

Comment: @H.Tacon I tired it but nothing happened it asked me for more commands.

Comment: @ABhelp I don't understand what you means with "asked me for more commands". Do you get a error message? Comment on my answer below, to that the other people don't receive unnecessary notifications

Answer (score 0):

Assming that are one command per line, you can do the following

```
import subprocess as sp

with open("commands.txt") as f:
    [sp.call(line) for line in f.read().splitlines()]
```

Comment: what if they aren’t shell commands? don’t assume anything until OP gives more clarification

Comment: Give me an example of command which, if it is properly configured to run in your machine, could not run in a terminal, and then I will give you reason.

Comment: @aws_apprentice nevermind, know the OP said that are shell commands and I am no more making assumption by my own